# Scope of IO defined variables

Tags: haskell

I've discovered that when doing IO in Haskell, variables that are assigned using the `<-` operator are only in scope for the statements immediately after them - not in `where` clauses.

For example:

```
main :: IO()
main =  do
          s <- getLine
          putStr magic
            where
              magic = doMagic s
```

This won't work as `s` is not in scope.  I did some research to confirm it and found [this](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/io.html) article:

> Unlike a `let` expression where variables are scoped over all definitions, the variables defined by `<-` are only in scope in the following statements.

So how can I make `s` available for use in the `where` clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the general let form, there's a special let form for use with do syntax you can use instead:

```
main :: IO()
main =  do
          s <- getLine
          let magic = doMagic s
          putStr magic
```

`magic` is available in all following lines in the block.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `magic` is a function. Therefore you can do something like:

```
magic m = doMagic m
```

Or:

```
magic = \m-> doMagic m
```

And call it like so:

```
putStrLn $ magic s
```

Of course, as you already researched, the sensible thing to do when you can reuse your computed `magic` is to use a `let ... in` expression, and nest the calls:

```
let magic_str = magic s in
  putStrLn magic_str
```

Comment: That's great.  I think for my particular situation I'll use `let`.

Answer (score 1):

`let` is the practical way to handle this. But it may be worth unpacking what's really going on here. The `do` statement isn't what's causing the scoping trouble.

Remember that

```
 main =  do
      s <- getLine
      putStr magic
        where
          magic = doMagic s
```

is equivalent to this:

```
main = getline >>= \s ->
       putStr magic
          where magic = doMagic s
```

If we put in some parentheses, this is:

```
main = getline >>= (\s -> putStr magic) where magic = doMagic s
```

This is where the scope of `s` comes from: it's the argument to a lambda expression, and it only exists within that lambda expression. Try to use it in a `where` clause outside of that lambda, and you get a "not in scope" error.

`let` works because `let` and `where` parse differently. With parentheses for clarity:

```
foo   = (\x -> let y = x in y)  -- Works fine
foo'' = (\x -> y) where y = x   -- y is not in scope
```

This is what's causing the problem; it's not specific to IO, or to `do` statements.

Comment: This is incorrect. Your example parses as `main = (getLine >>= \s -> putStr magic) where magic = doMagic s`, and _that_ is the source of the scoping error. The `where` is _not_ inside the lambda.

Comment: Interesting. How about `foo = \x -> y where y = x`? Does that parse as `foo = (\x -> y) where y = x`? Or is that a separate issue that happens to give the same error message?

Comment: Yes, it parses as `foo = (\x -> y) where y = x`. From [the report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#function-bindings), we can see that `where` blocks are always associated with a binding, and in particular are not part of the expression syntax.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I'd checked the report, but the notation was somewhat opaque to me.